# How to define models in django that provides custom values based on pre-selection for a field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Given the following model that stores the user's wish list for reading books:

```
class ReadingList(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, blank=False, default=None, db_column='user_id')
    book= models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user_id', book),)
```

I want to create a model that helps in tracking the time spent in the reading the book on different days which looks something like this:

```
class ReadingTracker(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(ReadingList, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='user', blank=False, db_column='user_id')
    book= models.ForeignKey(ReadingList, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='book-to-read', blank=False, db_column='book')
    time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    time_spent = models.floatfield()
```

On the client-side (corresponding to ReadingTracker) for both the fields `user_id` and `book`
I see that `ReadingList object (1)`, `ReadingList object (2)`, ... are listed. But, this is not working as expected.
What I want to achieve are the following:

1. For `user_id` field I want to see the something like **dummy_uid1**, **dummy_uid2**, ... to be listed.
2. Consider dummy_uid1 wants to read book1 and book2 whereas dummy_uid2 wants to read book1 and book3.
   When **dummy_uid1** is selected as `user_id`, I want only **book1** and **book2** to be listed for selection.

How do I define the model in django rest framework to achieve this?
Any suggestions related to the above would be much appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this question:

1. If you want to see a different value than `ReadingList object (1)` then you need to define the `__str__` value of your model, you can do this like so:

   ```py
   class ReadingList(models.Model):
      ...

      def __str__(self):
         return f'{self.user_id}' # return whatever string you want to display
   ```
2. If you want to just display the books for a particular user then you can use a `filter()` (see the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/)):

   ```py
   reading_list = ReadingList.objects.get(...)
   ReadingTracker.objects.filter(user_id=reading_list)
   ```

However, I would add that you have a `user_id` on your ReadingList object which does seem to connect to a User model, but your `user_id` on ReadingTracker is a ForeignKey relation to ReadingList, which is confusing. I would suggest renaming the field or actually making it link to the User model (though this is unnecessary as you can still filter by User through the ReadingList model).

Comment: 2. So, you are suggesting that I define a filter() in the post() to restrict the user from making an entry for an unplanned book (Eg. dummy_uid1 should not to be allowed to add a tracker entry for book3). Right?

3. Regarding the user_id on ReadingTracker being a ForeignKey relation to ReadingList, well I defined it like that because I did all the users in UserInfo model to be listed. I wanted to restrict the users only to those who have an entry in the ReadingList. Perhaps it can be achieved by a conditional statement rather than define the model as shown in RegardingTracker. Right?

Comment: You can get the reading lists connected to a UserInfo object like so: `user_info.readinglist_set.all()` where `user_info` is the object that you have already selected from the DB. Setting the ForeignKey to ReadingList doesn't filter anything as such, it just creates a relationship to that other model - which I think is what you want. I would still recommend renaming it and making sure your fields clearly described what they are. For example, you have a field called `book` which is actually a `ReadingList`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :). I will incorporate in my project. I updated the `ReadingList` model, now the `user_id` is linked to `UserInfo` model. However, I am facing a new problem. When I give `{... "book" : "book1"}` it says **Expected pk value, received str**.

Comment: Is that on `ReadingTracker`? That's because "book" is a `ReadingList` FK relation, so it expects a primary key value and not a string. You can either pass in the object or the PK to get it to work

Comment: Yes, it is on `ReadingTracker`.  I tried passing the object but it saves the object `id` and not the name of the book (which is given in `book` in `ReadingList`. Do you think perhaps it is a good idea to store the books coming from `ReadingList` in a new model called `Books` which has one charfield named book_name which is also a unique?

Comment: This is what I meant by your field names should match what they do :) because `book` on `ReadingTracker` isn't *actually* a book but a foreign key to `ReadingList`. You can access the `book` attribute of `ReadingList` with a through relationship, but again I would recommend a rename first. Having a separate `Book` model would be better, I would suggest a many-to-many field as many reading lists could have many books and vice versa.

Comment: I am fairly new to django. Thank you for being patient with my questions :). I will spend some time on your feedback and then get back to you :).